# php - regex - preg-match

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with my regex.

Here is the code and the output from an array:

Code:

```
foreach ($sizeNameFin as $key => $value) {
    echo("<br>");
    echo($value);
    echo("<br>");
}
```

output:

```
Vorhang mit Vorhangband 150 / 250
Vorhang mit Vorhangband 150 / 250
Vorhang mit Vorhangband 150 / 250
Vorhang mit Vorhangband 150 / 250
```

So and now I need only this part: "150 / 250"

I have tried:

```
foreach ($sizeNameFin as $key => $value) {

    print_r((preg_match('/[0-9]*[ ][\/][ ][0-9]*/',$value)));
    echo("<br>");
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
```

So it only shows me the first figure, but not 150, and so on.

I could undertand if I write `[0-9]` in my RegEx but there is a `*` behind the alphabet, so should he take the 150 or not?

Comment: Just `str_replace` `'Vorhang mit Vorhangband '` with empty string, if that's always the same?

Comment: [*`preg_match()` returns `1` if the pattern matches given subject, `0` if it does not, or `FALSE` if an error occurred.*](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-match.php) Use `if (preg_match('/[0-9]+ \/ [0-9]+/',$value, $matches)) { echo $matches[0]; }`

Comment: the brackets around single characters are useless, you can use `/[0-9]* \/ [0-9]*/` wich is more readable. also, be aware that your regex will match a string like this `" / "` (no numbers) if you need numbers, you should use `+` instead of `*`

Comment: Jeto
-No, because I have 26000 values ​​and not always the same words - thank you for the comment
WiktorStribiżew
- Thank you Sir ! thats the solution
ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ
- thank you for that note :)